# Why the cycle function cannot work with empty list?

Tags: haskell

I used the function [cycle](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:cycle) in some of my projects and today I discovered it isn't a total function, as shown by this GHCI example:

```hs
λ> Data.List.cycle []
*** Exception: Prelude.cycle: empty list
```

I know that Haskells tries to use total functions (except for the fundamental functions `head` and `tail`) and  I'm not entirely sure of why `cycle` is not one of them. In my mind, the `cycle` of the empty list is the empty list and I don't see problems with this. Why `cycle` for empty lists throws an error?

**EDIT**:
Based on the first answers, I think my idea is not completely clear: I don't want `cycle []` to be a computation that never ends. On contrary, I think `cycle []` should be the:

```
cycle :: [a] -> [a]
cycle [] = []
cycle xs = xs ++ cycle xs
```

The `[]` is the `cycle []` because all the operations do exactly what I except. For instance, `take 3 []` is `[]` and thus `take 3 (cycle [])` could be `[]`. What's the problem with this solution?

Comment: `cycle` *is* defined for empty list. You can define it as `cycle x = let y = x ++ y in y`. But `head (cycle [])` is an error with this definition anyways; however, `Exception: Prelude.cycle: empty list` is a way better error message than `Exception: <<loop>>`, which is what the above definition produces.

Comment: @user2407038 You have a funny definition of "defined"! `cycle []` is semantically equivalent to `undefined`...

Comment: I agree - I can't see a reason not to use `cycle [] = []`.

Comment: @AndrewC Wouldn't ``cycle [] = []`` make no sense because cycle is defined as returning an **infinite** list for every input?

Comment: @ThreeFx You make a valid point, but if you add 0 infinitely many times, you still get zero.* (*To be cardinality-specific, this infinity means countably many, like the number of natural numbers - this is how many times you see `"abc"` in `cycle "abc"`.) I don't have a problem with cycle behaving differently on `[]` to how it behaves on non-empty lists, and we all agree this is inevitable with `cycle`, but maybe a finite empty list with no error message is easier to handle.

Comment: @AndrewC I emphatically disagree. Adding special cases to handle an error condition *later* is wrong. `cycle` creates an infinite list. If you have to check whether the result is empty or not, you're adding error checking late. Why not check whether the input is empty or not, and save yourself the trouble by reporting the error closer to where it actually happened?

Comment: @Carl "Wrong" is a strong word for returning the empty list on empty input, especially since it's already a special case in the source code. Cycle doesn't create an infinite list, it creates a cyclic list. Admittedly in practice it's hard to tell the difference, but also in practice it's hard to check for `error "Prelude.cycle: empty list"`.

Comment: I don't see the empty list as necessarily an error case anyway; In mathematics you can make cyclic groups with elements of finite, infinite or zero order, just as you can cycle a finite list, an infinite list or a trivial list. It's making the trivial list special with some sort of error or non-termination which is adding an unusual special case. Checking for the empty list and behaving appropriately is standard, and a good thing unless you have some compelling reason, and I'm not convinced that you felt you should always have infinite output is good enough. `zip` silently truncates similarly.

Comment: @Carl I can check the input at runtime also for `head` and `tail` but I still think partial functions are bad. I prefer a total function that tells me in its type that it isn't defined always, like `Data.Maybe.listToMaybe`, instead of a partial function that requires me to check before, like `Data.List.head`. Why? Simply because the second one is error prone.
Still, while I understand why `head` works like that, the problem that I have with `cycle` is that I don't get why it should be partial and thus error prone. I was using it and I introduced errors without realising it.

Comment: @mariop You get the error for the very simple reason that it's *better* than the alternative of hanging as it attempts to produce the next element. The proper way to make `cycle` total involves using types for nonempty lists. Producing an empty list if the input is empty is even worse than hanging - it's silently propogating an error condition by returning nonsense. Might as well be PHP if that's what it's going to do.

Comment: @Carl I'm not saying it should return "nonsense" (why `Maybe` is nonsense anyway and errors not?), the point of this question is that it could be total by its own while `head` requires to return `Maybe` if you want to make it total. That's why I'm asking, `cycle` undefined for `[]` doesn't make sense for me.

Comment: @Carl It's no more propagating an error than `take`, `zip`, and countless other functions that return an empty list on empty input.

Comment: @AndrewC Different functions are different things. Many functions produce arbitrary-length lists as output. `cycle`, on the other hand, produces an infinite list as output.

Comment: @Carl Cycle should satisfy the law `take (length xs) (cycle xs) = xs` but at the moment it doesn't. (And cyclic and infinite aren't the same.) There are three common semantic interpretations of lists: functions/maps from an initial segment of the natural numbers, where `xs+xs` means add the length of `xs` to the indices and make the union of the two maps, non-determinism, where `xs+xs` means give me the same options again, and ziplists, where `xs+xs` means when you're done combining with `xs`, combine with `xs` again. In all three cases, `cycle []` should mean the same as `[]`.

Comment: @Carl `cycle [] = []` isn't nonsense any more than `zip "Hello" [] = []` is nonsense.

Comment: `[]` is only an error condition for other non-total functions like `head`.

Comment: @AndrewC - `take (length xs) (cycle xs)` seem to hold with the current `cycle`. `take (length []) (cycle []) == []`.  What case does the law not currently hold?

Comment: @Davorak Hehehe yes, because of lazy evaluation of course. Nevertheless, the semantic argument stands, and the use of error here is an ugly and inconsistent wart.

Comment: @Davorak How's about `zip (cycle xs) xs == zip xs xs = zip xs (cycle xs)`

Comment: @AndrewC - I think you have to strict in pattern matching on one element in zip so that one works as a potential law to follow. So to be constant with `cycle [] == []` it sounds like you need at least Dan Burton suggestion below, `tail [] == []`, it would then be odd if `init` did not receive a similar change `init [] == []`, the documentation should not refer to circular list, "cycle ties a finite list into a circular one, "(I think the behavior in your `zip` example is currently correct for circular lists, maybe refer to 'cycle'ing the elements instead to avoid confusion.

Comment: @AndrewC - One further consequence is that you can not think of `cycle` as a fix point any longer.  Right now `cycle ls == fix (ls++)` but this would not hold if `cycle [] == []`.  Not sure if there are any other consistency issues or  differences.

Comment: @Davorak But that would give non-termination on empty input! You have to be a die-hard fan of crashing your program to prefer the `fix` definition to the current one. Even if it weren't causing unproductive non-temination, no-one's using `fix` to define it today, why is it a problem to not use `fix` in the future?

Comment: And of couse I can think of it as a fixed point. Which equation do you want the output of `fix f` to obey? The point of  `fix f` is to find the value `a` such that `f a = a`. You have to accept that intellectually and mathematically, `[]` _is_ the fixed point of `[]++`. The fact that some code designed to find that fixed point fails to produce it in finite time is a good argument to match on that pattern and tell the compiler the correct answer.

Comment: The fixed point argument is the weakest one I've heard yet against `[]`, since it explains why `[]` is the answer. I might add that `cycle xs` should logically be the fixed point of both `(++xs)` and `(xs++)`. One of these is useful for producing values within a finite time and the other isn't, and since we're smart we point the compiler at the answer that's productive rather than the non-termination one. Do `[]` the same, easy, sensible `cycle [] = []` definition.

Comment: @AndrewC - Yep I knew/know the fix point of `[]++` is `[]`, but that is not something that you can express currently as a fix point in Haskell. I do not have a strong opinion on if the design should be changed currently. Mostly because I do not do not think I currently understand all the corner cases yet. I am pointing out that making `cycle [] == []` pushes around where the inconsistencies in the design are and not just fixing an inconsistency. I would rather my program consistently cashing under the same conditions, rather then inconsistently cash due to inconsistent design.

Comment: @Davorak You don't mean it can't be expressed in haskell, you mean that a particular function designed to find fixed points fails to find this one. All the more reason for the programmer to specify. I would rather my program _never_ crash on the empty list, which is why I avoid partial functions like head as much as I can and use exhaustive pattern matching instead. It's good practice to avoid crashing but rather politely explain to the user why you can't proceed. I can check for [] very easily, and often it's perfectly find. Let the programmer decide what they want to do with [], don't crash.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do not have any special insight into the mind(s) of the people who implemented the `cycle` function.

The [prelude has the following to say about cycle](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:cycle):

> cycle ties a finite list into a circular one, or equivalently, the infinite repetition of the original list. It is the identity on infinite lists.

Traditionally when you think of a circularly linked list, [wiki entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linked_list#Circular_list) you have:
[image: Screenshot from wiki]

How would I express a circular empty list? A pointer going to itself? But even that does not fit.

My best explanation is that circular lists are not normal lists.  They are different beasts with different semantics.  Just like `head` is really only full defined on non-empty empty list because there is no first element of an empty list, `cycle` is only fully defined on non-empty lists because there is no empty circular linked list.

Comment: You were consistent until you denied that it would be a pointer pointing to itself, since that (a thunk that evaluates to a thunk) is what the definition would be if you kept it consistent across any list input. Clearly that would be even less helpful than crashing the program is. I struggle to think of circumstances where crashing the whole program is better than returning the empty list.

Comment: I find it strange that people quote the comment in the prelude next to the definition in the prelude as an authority to justify their reasoning for not editing the prelude. Even if it said "don't edit this" there might be a case for editing it if it caused unnecessary program crashes. head _has_ to crash with that type signature, there's no possible correct answer on an empty list (ideally it would return a Maybe, and certainly read should), but cycle can return the entirely logical, consistent empty list. No need to crash the whole program.

Comment: By the way, I think this is the most convincing out of the wrong answers!

Comment: I accept the answer because I agree on the fact that circular lists are not normal lists. I disagree with Prelude design, by the way, because cycle has not a clear definition but more an intuition on what the result could be. Without a clear definition of cycle, one could in theory implement it as he want.

Answer (score 7):

`cycle` is actually defined as returning an infinite list for all input. If it attempted to do that naively with an empty input, it would sit in an infinite loop. The error condition is slightly more informative with the same denotational semantics.

### Edit:

Since people don't seem to understand what I mean when I say that empty output is bad, consider this simple function:

```
labelElements :: [a] -> [b] -> [(a, b)]
labelElements labels elements = zip (cycle labels) elements
```

It's nice and simple, with an obvious error condition when the list of labels is empty.  If cycle returned an empty list on empty input, it'd make `labelElements` silently propogate that bug to its output.  At the moment, it screams and yells that you messed up instead.  One of these is far better than the other.

Comment: It's not imperative to use the naive definition - you could use `cycle [] = []` without infinte loops.

Comment: @AndrewC Then you're expanding the definition with special cases. It's a lot nicer to know that cycle *always* results in an infinite list. The semantics are simpler, and there are fewer special cases to check for.

Comment: I disagree that empty output is a bug in your edit example. If I pop that in a GUI program where a user chooses both the labels and the elements, it's the _right_ thing to do to produce empty output until they fill in both. It's OK to check for `[]` and helpfully point this out to them, but it's absolutely the wrong thing to crash the whole program. If I use `cycle [] = []` the GUI just works. With the current `cycle [] = error "cycle: empty list"` you have to check for `[]` to stop your programming crashing. Don't force `error` on people unless it's necessary.

Comment: By this argument, `zip` itself should crash both on empty input, and on length mismatch. No, no, please no.

Comment: There's a big difference between "empty output is sometimes bad" and "empty output should crash every program that uses this function".

Comment: If empty output is a problem for your users, check for it and react accordingly, preferably with a polite explanation of what to do. Crashing with an uncustomised error message is surely _always_ a problem for your users.

Answer (score 3):

The problem arises when it comes to accessing elements in the list. A self-defined cycle function operating on a non-empty list has no problems when being accessed but trying to get, for example, the first 3 elements of the cycled empty list results in an infinite loop:

```
cycle' xs = xs ++ cycle' xs

take 3 (cycle' [1,2]) -- returns [1,2,1]
take 3 (cycle' [])    -- still looping
```

Comment: True, but if you define `cycle' [] = []` then `drop 3 (cycle' [])` gives `[]` without infinite loop. However, `head (cycle' [])` would be an error, certainly.

Answer (score 3):

Note that as it is currently defined, it is consistent with `tail`.

```
tail [] = error ...
```

`cycle` is conceptually related to `tail`. When you `cycle` a list, that means that you can repeatedly look to its `tail` and never reach the "end" (`[]`), because it is a cycle. (See Davorak's image.) In other words, it is always safe to use `tail` on a `cycle`'d list, assuming, of course, that it was safe to use `cycle` on that list in the first place.

I, for one, think it is a perfectly reasonable thing to define.

```
tail [] = []
cycle [] = []
```

But you should redefine both `cycle` *and* `tail` for consistency.

Answer (score 1):

The intent of `cycle` as described in the documentation is:

```
import Data.List.Nonempty
import Data.Stream.Infinite

cycle :: NonEmpty a -> Stream a
```

The authors of the `Prelude` use a partial function for passing in an empty list, which is conceptually a type error, similar to `head` and `tail`.

If you'd like a cycle that returns `[]` it's as easy as:

```
myCycle :: [a] -> [a]
myCycle xs = if null xs then xs else cycle xs
```

See: [semigroups](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/semigroups-0.15/docs/Data-List-NonEmpty.html) for the definition of `NonEmpty` and [streams](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/streams-3.2/docs/Data-Stream-Infinite.html) for the definition of `Stream` and a total definition of [`cycle`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/streams-3.2/docs/Data-Stream-Infinite.html#v%3acycle).